# Why cant I use Type() instance as a generic Type Parameter?

Tags: dart

Let's say am storing functions with type information in a map

```
static final Map<int,Tuple2<Function,Type>> _taskToRunMap = <int,Tuple2<Function,Type>>{}
```

and I want to be able to convert them to their original type upon retrieval.

```
static Type _getTaskToRunType(int taskToRunHash) => _taskToRunMap[taskToRunHash].item2;

static T _getTaskToRun<T extends Function>(int taskToRunHash) => _taskToRunMap[taskToRunHash].item1 as T;

static Future<T> getExecutable<T extends Function>(int taskToRunHash) async {
    return _getTaskToRun<T>(taskToRunHash);
}
final taskType = _getTaskArgsType(12345);
getExcecutable<_taskType>(12345);
```

When I call getExecutable, then I will get an error saying that "taskType isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument".

I do understand that Type() is a class, that, as explained in the API reference is a **Runtime representation of a type.**

So

```
final typeMap = <String,Type>{"string":String};
Type getType(String key) {
    return typeMap[key];
}


void main() {
  print(getType("string"));
}
```

Will return String, what I don't understand is why instances of Type can't be used as generic parameters.

Can someone please explain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: It's unsafe and it may increase program size.

Type arguments may have bounds. A `foo<X extends num>(X a, X b) => ...` function may only be called with a type argument which extends `num`. If you could use a `Type` object as argument, there is not enough information to statically check that you satsify the bounds, and if not, it will just be a run-time error. (That could be avoided by making `Type` objects generic, so `int` as an expression has static type `Type<int>`).

Dart separates type arguments/type variables from normal data flow so that it can better static analyse which types can occur as type variables.
When you evaluate a type as an expression (either a type literal or a type variable), it evaluates to a `Type` object. There is no way (outside of `dart:mirrors`) to go in the other direction. You cannot create a new *type* at run-time which wasn't there as a type in the original program.
Allowing a `Type` object (run-time data) to become the value of a type variable breaks this separation, and could cause larger programs when compiled to, e.g., JavaScript.

The reason it may create larger programs is that it makes tree-shaking harder. When compiling Dart to JavaScript, it is important to reduce the output size. To do that, the compiler uses what is known as "tree shaking", which is basically static garbage collection of your program. If some part of the program is definitely never used, it's not included in the output. (This is the reason JavaScript compiled Dart does not support `dart:mirrors`—through mirrors every part of the program is reachable at run-time, so you can tree-shake nothing).

Dart *types* are something that can be tree-shaken too. 
If you never use a specific type in an `is type` test (or similar), then the program does not need to retain all the information needed to implement that test. Objects implementing the type need not remember that they do so. In practice, many types are never used like that, so it is a real saving in program size.

However, if you have code doing `is T` where `T` is a type argument, then you *also* need to know which types that `T` can refer to, otherwise you cannot tree-shake the type information.

If your program never uses a specific type as a generic type argument, then the compiler knows that a `T` cannot refer to that type. All type arguments in Dart are either type literals or other type variables, so only the types that occur as type literals can ever be the value of type variable (those that occur there *after* inferring missing type arguments, not just those in the literal source.)

However, if you could use a `Type` object as a type argument, then it becomes much harder to see which types can flow into a type variable. Then any type which has a `Type` object created might also become a type argument, and the compiler cannot statically determine the *data flow* of those type variables.